# Converting an array of values to an object with dummy properties in JSONata

Tags: jsonata

I am trying to convert the following data structure:

```
[
  "apple",
  "banana",
  "carrot"
]
```

...into:

```
{
  "apple": "null",
  "banana": "null",
  "carrot": "null"
}
```

...as the environment I'm doing this in is basing certain functionality on key names rather than values.

I have tried using my JS knowledge to implement this via the `$reduce` function, but I'm obviously not understanding the data-oriented nature of this language:

```
$reduce($$, function($acc, $cur) {
  $acc[$cur] = 'null'
}, {})
```

The above merely returns `false`. I have read through the docs and cannot locate any information on building up objects like you would in other languages. Any help would be greatly appreciated; thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got very close, but `$acc[$cur] = 'null'` expression does not assign a value to a key inside an array it compares an `$acc` variable filtered by `$cur` expression to a `'null'` string.

You have to use the [$merge function](https://docs.jsonata.org/object-functions#merge) to extend the `$acc` object on each iteration:

```
$reduce($$, function($acc, $cur) {
  $merge([$acc, { $cur: "null" }])
}, {})
```

See on the live playground: https://stedi.link/p9aWDjY

A shorter way to do that would be:

```
$${$: "null"}
```

It uses the [reduce operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#---reduce) to group by `$` which would be each entry of the input array.

See it live: https://stedi.link/waN2p7B

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and the explanation regarding single equals being a comparison operator (not sure how I missed that). I had a sneaking suspicion `$merge` would be useful here, but I wasn't sure how to implement in this context. Thank you for your help!